# Angular ag-grid how to add a column before autogroupcolumn

Tags: ag-grid-angular, angular11

I am new to angular aggrid. the grid displays records with autogroupcolumndef set. Now i want to add a column with context menu before the grouping column. Can anyone help  how to do this?

```
<ag-grid-angular
    #agGrid
    style="height:calc(100vh - 12rem)"
    class="ag-theme-balham ag-grid indent"
    [rowData]="data$ | async"
    [treeData]="true"
    [animateRows]="true"
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    [autoGroupColumnDef]="autoGroupColumnDef">
  </ag-grid-angular>



readonly autoGroupColumnDef = {
    headerName: 'Name',
    minWidth: 350,
    cellClass: 'indented',
    cellRendererParams: {
      suppressCount: true,
      innerRenderer: 'UserImageInTreeComponent',
      isManager: false,
      showNameAsHyperlink: true
    }
  };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround:

```
gridOptions.columnApi.moveColumn('yourColumn', 0);
```

change `yourColumn` with your column name and `0` with the index.